# Send large files with Telegram API BOT

Tags: telegram-bot, large-files

Hi everyone on a node project I'm trying to send files to my private channel on Telegram via bot API. However, I get an error when I try to send a video of even 100MB.

Reading on the net I noticed that it is possible to send up to 50MB but I find some discussions where it mentions the opportunity to send files greater than 1 GB.

Do you know how this is possible? Is there a step-by-step guide? I'm using the EXPRESS framework

I hope someone can help me

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I read this guide but I do not understand some points.
If you know the answer... What changes from the standard procedure? Would the file be stored on my server? So should I have enough space for each file sent? Why does this method provide fewer limitations than the normal procedure?

Comment: Do you use any library for the telegram bot?

Comment: I tried some as node-telegram-bot-api (the project is in NODE) but I get Reply from Telegram all the time: {"ok":false,"error_code":413,"description":"Request Entity Too Large"}
trying to send a simple video of 100.00MB

Comment: Hmm I don't know maybe its the limitation?